# ruby hash keys compare_by_identity

Tags: ruby, hash

I have the following:

```
h1 = {}
h1.compare_by_identity
h1['a'] = '1'
h1['a'] = '2'
h1['a'] = '3'
a_key = h1.keys.first
p h1[a_key]
```

And it prints 1, how do I make it return 2 or 3?

Comment: What is `compare_by_identity`?

Comment: @sawa [Hash#compare_by_identity](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Hash.html#method-i-compare_by_identity)

Comment: @Stefan Thanks for the information. I didn't know it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how do I make it return 2 or 3?

```
h1[h1.keys[0]] # => "1"
h1[h1.keys[1]] # => "2"
h1[h1.keys[2]] # => "3"
```

You can of course access the list of values directly, but I don't think this is in the spirit of your question:

```
h1.values # => ["1", "2", "3"]
```

Answer (score 0):

that's because `'a'` it's a different object each time.

```
'a'.object_id == 'a'.object_id
=> false
a = 'a'
a.object_id == a.object_id
=> true
```

You can try using the same object/instance, or a Symbol.

```
h1 = {}
h1.compare_by_identity

h1['a'] = 1
puts h1['a'] # => nil

a = 'a'
h1[a] = 2
puts h1[a] # => 2

h1[:a] = 3
puts h1[:a] # => 3
```